Как сделать выбор варианта y/n через цикл?
вот код, хочу сделать для него подтверждение типа y/n
while variant != 
variant = str(input())

Как это сделать?

как 2 пальца... Вот тут пример в ответе второй вариант как раз то, что спрашиваете

tio.run
def confirm(msg):
  val = input(msg + ' [Y]es/[N]o').lower()

  while val not in ('y', 'yes', 'n', 'no'):
    val = input('Попробуйте ещё раз [Y]es/[N]o').lower()

  return val[0] == 'y'

print(confirm("Небо голубое?"))
print(confirm("Вода красная?"))


while True:
    variant = str(input())
    if variant.lower() in ('y', 'n'):
        break

